# Program Designing Approach

Tags: java, c++, oop, visual-c++, software-design

I would appreciate any help/guidance with the program design approach for the following.

I am developing a class in which I have the class, the attributes figured out, which is as follows;

```
class PanelBlock{

    public: 
        PanelBlock();

    private:
        TCHAR m_sSlope[PANEL_NAME_LENGTH];  // To store the Slope

        bool m_bTopPanel;     // This is to identify the
        bool m_bMidPanel;     // location of the PanelBlock.
        bool m_bBotPanel;

        // Similarly we have it for other attributes.
        // My Question here is, 
        // Is it better to have a TCHAR instead of 3/5 booleans here?

        TCHAR m_sPanelLocation[PANEL_LOCATION_LENGTH];

}
```

My Question here is,

> Is it better to have a **TCHAR/String** instead of 3/5 booleans here? In my
>   application code, I would just compare the **TCHAR/String** with a particular
>   **TCHAR/String**, say if the location is TOP, do task A, or does having booleans
>   have any advantages that I am missing?
>
> Also, I have **around 8 attributes** for which I will need booleans to
>   identify if it is on the **Top, middle or bottom**.

Any help/guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using `TCHAR` because those are display strings and you have the need to switch between multibyte and wide characters with the same source, or is it something else?

Comment: @RetiredNinja You are correct those are the display Strings.

Comment: @user93353 I understand enums are a good choice, wanted to know the advantages/disadvantages in the above approach.

Answer (score 0):

`bool` is a one byte type while `TCHAR` depending on its use can be up to two bytes. From the point of memory size and optimization, `bool`s are more optimized and fast because they're either 0 or 1. You should have mentioned your goal for this change to happen. Lots of aspects are involved.

Comment: `sizeof(bool)` is implementation-defined. It can be 1 byte, or more, depending on your compiler & architecture.

Comment: @Fabien You're right, I'm assuming Visual C++ as compiler and a PC as my machine.

Answer (score 0):

"Better" is subjective, and the correct approach depends on what you mean by it.

When writing new code, I always define "better" in these terms, in this order:

1. **Simplicity.**  Clear, easy to understand code is better than complex, obfuscated code because it is easier to extend and fix.
2. **Genericity.** Code that is generic is better than code with a very narrow scope of applicability because it reduces the amount of code you have to write.  Hopefully this in turn reduces the number of bugs you have to fix.
3. **Efficiency of speed.** Fast code is better than slow code.
4. **Efficiency of space.** Less memory use is better than more.

As this applied to your code, I would probably design it to use a single `bool` for every distinct attribute, rather than trying to create a single integral type with `OR`ed flags, etc.  If the booleans are mutually exclusive, then I would use a single `enum` to express them all.

It is important to avoid prematurely micro-optimizing your code, because doing so will necessarily make things more complex, less generic, and harder to maintain.  However that's no excuse for not selecting the correct algorithms in the first place.

As the code is written and tested against a real production environment, I'll profile my code and identify hotspots.  If I find any and identify them as things that need to be fixed, then my priorities shift:

1. **Efficiency of speed.** Fast code is better than slow code.
2. **Efficiency of space.** Less memory use is better than more.
3. **Simplicity.**  Clear, easy to understand code is better than complex, obfuscated code because it is easier to extend and fix.
4. **Genericity.** Code that is generic is better than code with a very narrow scope of applicability because it reduces the amount of code you have to write.  Hopefully this in turn reduces the number of bugs you have to fix.

**Simplicity** is still relatively important, especially when beginning to micro-optimize.  Optimizing pieces of code can easily result in complexity getting out of hand, making maintenance a nightmare.  Don't completely abandon simplicity on the altar of performance.

Answer (score 0):

While not the only main point to consider in design, it is generally a good maxim

```
When doing something, do it once.
```

You have three booleans, controlling the position of your item.  That means that to figure out the position of the item, you need to check three items.  In addition, to set the position of your item, you need to set one boolean `true`, and two booleans `false`.  It seems like you will be doing three things nearly every time you do something.

Consider this

```
public enum VerticalPanelPosition {
   TOP,
   MIDDLE,
   BOTTOM;
}
```

Now you can only have one location

```
private VerticalPanelPosition vPosition;
```

And only need to do "one thing, once"

```
public void setPosition(VerticalPanelPosition position) {
  vposition = position;
}
```

Sorry for the Java syntax, but given the context, I'll bet you can translate it into C# without much effort.

Good luck on getting better at design, it's one small step at a time, with lots of things to consider.

Comment: I like `When doing something, do it once`, which is why I was thinking of String comparisons. Definitely enums serves the purpose the best here. Appreciate your help Edwin.